# What's the best way to manage multiple websites within a single solution in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I often create several sub domains of a web project, such as blog.domain.com, www.domain.com and example.domain.com.  Typically I set these projects up within a single solution, along with any common class libraries, and assign each a static port number.  To view a specific site I right click a file in the solution explorer and "View in browser".

I'm working on a project with multiple MVC2 projects under VS 2010.  I seem to have lost the ability to "View in browser" from the context menu of a file, so I need to use the Set as start up project for a specific site, then Ctrl F5 to view a site. Workable but frustrating.

Is there a better way to manage multiple common sections of a site as different sites, or reason I can no longer see "View in browser" from the context menu?

Comment: The reason you don't see a "View in browser" option is because mvc isn't really a file based project.

Comment: Yes, I do get this, and it's never been ideal.  I would typically click the default doc in the root (The IIS 6 doc), or any view to open the Development server, then amend the URL to what it should be. I guess there must be a better way, or perhaps I should be running a separate solution per section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just discovered "Multiple Startup Projects" under the properties of the solution.  Not an ideal fix, but it saves me switching start up projects. It opens a Development Server for each project, and loads each site into a separate browser window when I ctrl F5.